# Log headers from http call in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

Hi I want to show the content of headers, is there a simple way?
This is my code:

```
 this.http.post(this.url,'{"username":"user","password":"123456"}')
.subscribe((res) => {
 var payload = res.json();
 var headers = res.headers;
 console.log('Content-Range: ' + headers.values());
```

and this is my error:

```
ERROR Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }
```

==================================UPDATE================================ 
I am trying to do a post request to a server, the body is correctly empty and it seems that angular go in the error state just after http.post because body is empty so i can't do a console.log.
I am interested only in headers I don't care in body.

Comment: try catching the error on the ajax call.

Comment: this javascript is not valid

Comment: if you want to log all headers, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers,null,2));`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this.

```
   login() {
     let params = new URLSearchParams;
    params.append('username',this.user);
    params.append('password',this.password);
        this.http.post(this.url,{header:header,search:params} )
            .map((response) => response.json())
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you missed closing paranthesis here `new URLSearchParams()`

Comment: No need of closing paranthesis

Comment: .subscribe((res) => {
         var payload = res.json();
         var headers = res.headers; you can check like this

Answer (score 0):

I just solve my problem exposing headers manually,
this is the code:

`res.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin")`;